# Functions like node_load() are not found

Tags: drush

I successfully installed Drush on Ubuntu 12.04, and I created a script containing the following line.

```php
print_r(node_load(10));
```

I am calling the script with `drush php-script --uri=http://localhost myscript.php` which returns the following error.

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load()

I also tried with `drush --uri=http://localhost cache-get`, but I get the following error.

> Command cache-get needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
> The drush command 'cache-get' could not be executed.
> Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.
> Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>
> - bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
> - connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
>   Drush was attempting to connect to:
>   Drupal version:  7.26
>   Site URI:  `http://localhost`
>   Database driver:  mysql
>   Database hostname: 127.0.0.1
>   Database username: **username** // This is shown correctly
>   Database name: **database_name**  // This is shown correctly
>   PHP executable: /usr/bin/php
>   PHP configuration:  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
>   PHP OS:  Linux
>   Drush version:  7.0-dev
>   Drush temp directory:  /tmp
>   Drush configuration:
>   Drush alias files:
>   Drupal root:  /opt/lampp/htdocs
>   Site path:  sites/default

Comment: are you running the command from the site root folder

Comment: Yes, I am calling drush from the site root folder.
In my case that is user@computer:/opt/lampp/htdocs/sites/default$

Comment: If you are calling drush from the site root folder, why do you need to specify the `--uri` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was missing.

In my case I had to install the mysql-client-core-5.5 package with `sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (user_load() and other functions were not found), but had a different solution.

For me, it turned out that my sql privileges on the database were not correct.

I found the error by running my script with the -d option:

```
drush -d scr /path/to/my/script.php
```

I noticed in the log it spewed out that it was getting an error connecting to the database. I apparently had messed up the privs when I set them up. I sql `grant`ed  the privs and my script ran just fine.

The error message about not being able to find a function was a total red herring.

Comment: Red herring indeed...