# user_load() and EntityFieldQuery not found when running script via Drush

Tags: 7, drush, bootstrapping

I'm trying to run a php script from the command line via Drush. When I tried to use EntityFieldQuery...

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
```

I got the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'EntityFieldQuery' not found in /path/to/my/script.php on line 43
```

So, I tried to make it even simpler, and just used this script:

```
<?php

print "inside script\n\n";
$user = user_load(1);
print "name: ".$user->name;

?>
```

But I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_load() in /path/to/my/script.php on line 17
```

It doesn't appear that drush is bootstrapping properly. Am I missing something? What do I need to do for drush to be able to use the drupal apis?

I read through [Drush php-script | Drupal functions such as node_load() are not being found](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/drush-php-script-drupal-functions-such-as-node-load-are-not-being-found), but I've got mysql client libraries already installed so that isn't a solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, WOW, I found the error by running my script with the -d option:

```
drush -d scr /path/to/my/script.php
```

I noticed in the log it spewed out that it was getting an error connecting to the database. I apparently had messed up the privs when I set them up. I regranted the privs and my script ran just fine.

The error message about not being able to find a function was a total red herring.

Comment: 3 years later I just had this problem again and Google searched to find out what was going wrong, found this incredibly helpful suggestion, and tried to upvote it... and StackOverflow told me I wasn't allowed to upvote my own answer. And that's when I realized -I- had posted this question and answer. /facepalm heh.